# "object doesn't support property or method" VBA login

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to login in this website using VBA but no success so far.

```
Option Explicit

Sub logintest()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "www.renovigi.solar/"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginusr") ' This is based on on your website

HTMLInput.Value = "TEST" 'Put the value of Usernamae

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginpwd") 'This is based on on your website

HTMLInput.Value = "TEST" 'Put the value of Password

Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginbtn") 'This is based on on your website

HTMLButton.Click


End Sub
```

I'm getting this error message.

> "object doesn't support property or method"

Comment: Please include the line that is highlighted when you get the error and click on debug.

Comment: `loginpwd` How did you get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the input elements and then set the values. also, you may try the alternative way which I have commented.

```
Sub logintest()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "www.renovigi.solar/"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginusr").Children(0)

'Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.querySelector("#loginusr input") ' This is based on on your website


HTMLInput.Value = "TEST" 'Put the value of Usernamae

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginpow").Children(0)
'Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.querySelector("#loginpow input") 'This is based on on your website

HTMLInput.Value = "TEST" 'Put the value of Password

Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginbtn") 'This is based on on your website

HTMLButton.Click


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Santosh! This is by far the best website with the best community I've ever seen.